# Is there a way to add a friend class that is itself but with different template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, private, friend

I was writing a numpy-equivalent variable-dimension array in C++.  I used a template class to store different kinds of datatypes in the array.

Eventually, I had to write a code for the datatype converting.  I would like to have the arrays to change their datatypes into another, so I wrote a constructor for the conversion.  However, the class had to access the private values of the class but with different template arguments.

The following is a minimal example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class my_class
{
private:
    T value;
    
public:
    // Constructor to initialize the data
    my_class(T value) : value(value) {}

    // Constructor for the conversion
    template<typename O>
    my_class(my_class<O> another)
    {
        value = static_cast<T>(another.value);   // Cast the type to T
    }
};
```

However when I try to run the following test code:

```cpp
int main()
{
    // Create an integer class
    my_class<int> a = 3;

    // Convert it to float
    my_class<float> b = a;

    return 0;
}
```

MSVC emits this error:

```
error C2248: 'my_class<int>::value': cannot access private member declared in class 'my_class<int>'
```

I tried adding a friend to the individual `my_class`es by following:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class my_class
{
    // ...

public:
    template <typename U>
    friend class my_class<U>;
    
    // ...
}
```

However this error occurred:

```
friend class my_class<U>;
             ^~~~~~~~~^
error C3772: 'my_class<U>': invalid friend template declaration
```

Is there a way to add a friend class that is itself but with different template arguments?
Alternatively, if that's not possible, is there a way to access the private methods/values of a class itself but with different template arguments?

However, I would prefer the friend approach, as it allows me to just add the friend once and access the private methods/values later on.

Comment: Side note, "I want to make something in language X that is also available as a language feature in language Y" is usually not a good thing. C++ has totally different concepts than Python.  C++ is a strongly typed language and Python is not. If in C++ you need to mix datatypes use `std::variant` (or maybe in your case an `std::vector<std::variant<...>>`). So the best kind of advise is don't do this and spent time investigating how C++ does things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

```
template <typename U>
friend class my_class;
```